# Blind source separation of convex mixture?

Tags: pca, independent-component-analysis

Suppose I have $n$ independent sources, $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ and I observe $m$ convex mixtures:
\begin{align}
Y_1 &= a_{11}X_1 + a_{12}X_2 + \cdots + a_{1n}X_n\\
...&\\
Y_m &= a_{m1}X_1 + a_{m2}X_2 + \cdots + a_{mn}X_n
\end{align}

with $\sum_j a_{ij} = 1$ for all $i$ and $a_{ij} \ge 0$ for all $i,j$.

What's the state of the art in recovering $X$ from $Y$?

PCA is out of the question because I need the components to be identifiable.
I've looked at ICA and NMF - I can't find any way to impose nonnegativity of the mixing coefficients for ICA, and NMF doesn't seem to maximize independence.

Comment: I would think that this should be called "nonnegative independent component analysis", but it seems that this name has been used for ICA with the nonnegativity constraint on the sources $X$, not on the mixing matrix $A$ (https://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/~markp/2003/Plumbley03-algorithms-c.pdf). So this does not apply to your case. Interesting question.

Comment: Don't you want the sums to run over j instead of i? Can you assume the sources are approximately gaussian? if they are unimodal and have sufficiently fast decay, it is possible that fitting a GMM would suffice.

Comment: @YairDaon Ah yes thanks, good catch. Unfortunately the sources are discrete and don't even look like mixtures of gaussians. But perhaps I could coarsely approximate them as gaussian mixtures and then further refine. But it would be nice to have something more general/robust

Comment: Your question looks like a difficult open research problem. It would be really cool if it gets answered here, but alas, there are not many specialists on ICA here (as manifested by the very low number of views and only a single upvote of your question), perhaps even none. Was a brave move to offer a bounty!

Comment: @amoeba I was worried it might just be open. But I'll hold out hope for the next 6 days!

Comment: What ICA algorithms have you tried? I'm a little rusty, but think the non-negativity assumption of the mixing coefficients can be imposed in some algorithms that assume certain models for the signals like the Weights-Adjusted Second Order Blind Identification (WASOBI) algorithm, as it assumes you can model the signals as AR processes and, thus, you can impose conditions in the coefficients.

Comment: @user43228 Can you give some context for the problem (ie what the sources are, why you need to solve it)? Also, more specifically: do the sources have a known, finite support?

Comment: The sources are all supported on the set {1,2,...,96}

Comment: Can you explicitly state in your question whether you are looking to discern independent signals, i.e. the matrix $A$ containing the coefficients $a_{ij}$ should be orthogonal?

Comment: @means-to-meaning The mixing matrix is nonnegative and the convex mixtures are true mixtures, i.e. this is not a vector quantization problem, so I don't think A should be orthogonal. As stated in the question, I am looking to as best as possible recover the signals under the assumption they are independent.

Comment: @Néstor These signals aren't really time series; I'm not sure they qualify as AR processes. But I don't know almost anything about the area so that could be wrong.

Comment: It doesn't matter if they are time series or not. AR models work fine on any indexed series, not only on time series.

Comment: This is not unique. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11634-014-0192-4 Mixture distributions are ubiquitous and also problematic for those organic applications that I have examined. I have yet to see a circumstance in which they are preferred over dependent processes like convolutions of components upon testing.

Comment: See my answer below with links to nonnegative independent component analysis.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is Non-negative Independent Component Analysis (nICA). nICA is a variant of ICA that incorporates non-negativity constraints, hence it maintains the desirable properties of ICA (maximization of statistical independence of the reconstructed sources) while also imposing non-negativity of the mixing coefficients. If would like to have both nonnegativity constraints and linear equality constraints on the mixing coefficients then you would need to use a quadratic programming solver (e.g. osqp) to calculate the updates, though I haven't seen an off-the-shelf implementation. See [this article and references therein](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/117762500700100023) and [Chapter 11 in this book](https://www.google.be/books/edition/Blind_Source_Separation/hQeaAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=cichocki%20%22nonnegative%20independent%20component%20analysis%22&pg=PT169&printsec=frontcover). Here is a [Matlab implementation](https://github.com/rsomervail/non-negative-ICA-matlab), and here is a [Python one](https://github.com/marcromani/cocktail/blob/master/src/cocktail/cocktail.py) of nICA, which would be a good start and with some modification could be made to also allow for linear equality constraints.

Answer (score 1):

This is just ICA with a constraint on the mixing matrix. Look up an ICA book or survey paper for cost functions associated with ICA, using fixed or adaptive source distributions depending on the distribution of the components. Then add a constraint that the rows of the mixing matrix satisfy the equality and inequality constraints, and use the update rule as the direction in a non-linear programming routine.

Comment: This is correct, but the OP would be better helped if you could give a good link to "an ICA book or survey paper for cost functions associated with ICA"... You also need to be a bit more specific than "and derive update rule using an optimization method". What optimization method in this case? Quadratic programming?

Comment: The ICA book by Hyvarinen would be a good start. The update rules for Extended Infomax or FastICA, formulated in terms of the mixing matrix rather than the unmixing matrix, represent a direction related to the gradient, for the vectorized mixing matrix. This can be used in a standard non-linear programming routine with equality and inequality constraints. The cost function, which is basically a log likelihood, has to be formulated as well. The Hyvarinen chapter on Maximum Likelihood methods should provide a likelihood function and corresponding (natural) gradient update.

Comment: I think the BSS book by Cichocki has natural gradient updates for the mixing matrix if the Hyrvarinen book doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

It could be achieved by using an exponential non-linearity instead of the typical/default tanh(), if X is also non-negative.

Formula 40 in https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/ahyvarin/papers/NN00new.pdf and available in most implementations.

E.g. in sklearn simply use fun='exp'
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.FastICA.html

Comment: Welcome to Stats.SE. Can you please edit your answer and expand it in order to explain the key steps of the links you provide? This way, the information is searchable in here (and sometimes links break). You may want to take a look at some [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). While you're at it, you can use [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: I don't think this would work - with transformation one also wouldn't have independence on the original scale - typically one would like hard nonnegativity constraints in problems like this... Nonnegative independent component analysis is what you would need here, see Chapter 11, https://www.google.be/books/edition/Blind_Source_Separation/hQeaAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=cichocki%20%22nonnegative%20independent%20component%20analysis%22&pg=PT169&printsec=frontcover. And my answer below.

Answer (score -2):

Transformation of variables is a good option when that linearizes the problem. That procedure can be used to increase the correlations, reduce the residuals, and decrease the number of parameters needed to produce a good fit to the data.

For example, $\ln Y=a_0+a_1\ln X_1+a_2\ln X_2\to Y=e^{a_0}X_1^{a_1}X_2^{a_2},$ might be vastly superior to $Y=a_0+a_1X_1+a_2X_2$. A hint as to what to do is often provided by examination of the data or its residuals. For example, if one has fan shaped heteroscedasticity of parameters, like in this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/6707938_An_improved_method_for_determining_renal_sufficiency_using_volume_of_distribution_and_weight_from_bolus_Tc-99m-DTPA_two_blood_sample_paediatric_data)
[image]

That particular type of log-log transform may be of interest. More generally, there are lots of transforms to consider: taking square roots, exponentiation, taking reciprocals, and so forth. Another indication of how one should treat the data comes from considering the physics of the problem. For example, if a regression problem cannot take negative $Y$-values, that problem may not be linear, as lines may become negative.

Comment: I don't think this would work - one also wouldn't have independence on the original scale - typically one would like hard nonnegativity constraints in problems like this... Nonnegative independent component analysis is what you would need here, see Chapter 11, https://www.google.be/books/edition/Blind_Source_Separation/hQeaAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=cichocki%20%22nonnegative%20independent%20component%20analysis%22&pg=PT169&printsec=frontcover. And my answer below.

Comment: @TomWenseleers Independence on the original scale is irrelevant when the original scale is unmotivated. The data above are mass (W) and volume (V) which are definite positive AND are inappropriately dimensioned to be properly related on the original scale. Frankly, I don't follow what you are saying, it doesn't compute.

Comment: Well that in this example the aim is to recover a set of orthogonal sources X_i. But what was required was orthogonality on the original untransformed scale X_i, not orthogonality on some log-log scale. And that's typically tackled using nonnegativity constrained independent component analysis (nnICA). Also, the aim is to decompose the signal in additive components, but a log transforms would decompose the signal in multiplicative components, which is not what is asked for here...

Comment: You would be claiming that a nonnegative matrix factorization would be equivalent to an unconstrained matrix factorization after log transform. But that's not the case as the latter would be a matrix decomposition into multiplicative rather than additive components. Plus we need the orthogonality constraints, so that would be nonnegative independent component analysis...

Comment: OK I see, but that's really not the question here... The question is how to deparate a number of independent sources for the cases where the observed signal is a nonnegative linear (convex) combination of the sources subject to the sources being independent of each other. Nonnegative independent component analysis would solve that problem.

Comment: @TomWenseleers Nonnegative component analysis would add nothing to the uses to which I applied the regression analysis. It can be "interesting" in certain situations, but is irrelevant to the uses to which I put the data analysis. Without transformation by taking logarithms, the regression has greater error, heteroscedascity, and lots of other red flags. Your comments are unhelpful.

Comment: Well anyway, I gave the references above. If there is heteroscedasticity it is also possible to fit models similar to nICA but using 1/variance weights, which are approx 1/(y+small epsilon) in case of Poisson noise...

Comment: @TomWenseleers Also useless.